# Pie chart uses (d3.layout.pie) , what Can I use instead in Line chart ? using d3.js and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, d3.js

Pie chart uses (d3.layout.pie) , what Can I use instead in Line chart ? I have a json file data stored in a server . I try to access this data but I could not . I looked for a similar example I found a pie chart example which is

```
 var force = d3.layout.force()
   .charge(-120)
   .linkDistance(30)
   .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);
```

How can I change this could or anyway else ((like d3.layout.stack)) to allow my line chart code to access the data and draw my line chart using d3.js ? My json file is a nested file which is :

```
   {"Id":466,"Name":"korea","Occurrences":

   [{"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1398207600000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":27},
   {"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1398726000000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":1},
   {"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1398898800000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":4},
   {"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1399071600000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":303}]}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. There are lots of examples for both line and stacked line (and area) charts.

Comment: The json data above is imported from a server side. I try to navigate this data to draw a area chart. The problem which I currently face is that json data is nested . My question is how I can navigate this data   to visualize the OccurrenceDate and OccurrenceFrequency to draw a area chart d3 ?

Comment: Here is an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211) that should get you started. It doesn't use nested data, but nests it implicitly so that with your data format it should actually be easier.